# How to add icon in label or label text in flutter textformfield

Tags: flutter, textfield

Here is my code : when I start typing the hint text overrides the label text if it is provided along with icon. label text can be used for proper UI but it only takes text. How to solve this?

```
         label: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Email Address",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Tooltip(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                    message:
                        "We use your email to validate your identity, create your user id, and to contact you for account-related matters.",
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.info,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        /* your code */
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

But my UI looks like this [image]

Comment: remove the padding  and try

Comment: If I remove the padding the icon moves to the right corner @Anandh-ஆனந்த்

Comment: @Sindu please add whole code

Comment: Sorry I reverted Every thing since I couldn't find what is the issue ..is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Form(
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            child: TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
              validator: (value) => validateEmail(value.toString())
                  ? null
                  : "Please enter a valid Email.",
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  labelText: 'User Name ',
                  hintText: 'Enter Your Name ',
                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort.. But I want it as icon widget so that I can add tooltip for that icon